# Проблема в написании кода для уравнения python (math domain error)

Tags: python

Задание 1:

1. Напишите программу, которая бы вычисляла заданное арифметическое выражение при заданных переменных. Ввод переменных осуществляется с клавиатуры. Вывести результат с 2-мя знаками после запятой.
   Задание 2:
   Для заданной функции примените префиксную нотацию. Ввод переменных осуществляется с клавиатуры. Вывести результат с 2-мя знаками после запятой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```py
import math
print ('A=')
A=int(input())
print ('B=')
B=int(input())
print ('C=')
C=int(input())
Q=math.sqrt(1+pow(math.tan(A),2)+B*pow(1/math.tan(C),2)-math.sqrt(3+math.log(A,math.e)+math.sin(B)))
Q = float('{:.2f}'.format(Q))
print (Q)
```

Line 8, math domain error
Не могу понять, в чём ошибка? Исходные данные A=1, B=2, C=3

Comment: а кто сказал, что ошибка?

Comment: Компилятор выдаёт ошибку

Comment: так вот надо взять эту ошибку и добавить в вопрос. Но сначала, конечно, прочитать и хотя бы попытаться понять, в чем она заключается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в извлечении квадратного корня из отрицательного числа. Если разбить формулу на части, это будет видно явно

```
import math

print('A=')
A = int(input())
print('B=')
B = int(input())
print('C=')
C = int(input())

p1 = pow(math.tan(A), 2)
p2 = B * pow(1 / math.tan(C), 2)
p3 = math.sqrt(3 + math.log(A, math.e) + math.sin(B))

print(1 + p1 + p2 - p3)  # -0.39295057290568014

Q = math.sqrt(1 + p1 + p2 - p3)

Q = float('{:.2f}'.format(Q))
print(Q)
```

```
-0.39295057290568014
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex20\PycharmProjects\test\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    Q = math.sqrt(1 + p1 + p2 - p3)
ValueError: math domain error
```

Если перевести A,B,C в радианы для тригонометрических функций, то результат получается без ошибки:

```
import math

print('A=')
A = int(input())
print('B=')
B = int(input())
print('C=')
C = int(input())

p1 = pow(math.tan(math.radians(A)), 2)
p2 = B * pow(1 / math.tan(math.radians(C)), 2)
p3 = math.sqrt(3 + math.log(A, math.e) + math.sin(math.radians(B)))

Q = math.sqrt(1 + p1 + p2 - p3)

Q = float('{:.2f}'.format(Q))
print(Q)
```

```
81.01
```

Comment: Получается, что вводные данные не корректны?

Comment: Не знаю, в каких единицах вводятся данные. Тригонометрические функции в Python принимают радианы. Если перевести в радианы, то ошибка исчезает (добавил в код). Или результатом может быть комплексное число, как написал @Pavel Orlov

Answer (score 1):

Если использовать модуль **sqrt** из **cmath**, то при получении переменной **Q**,
мы можем увидеть что она является комплексным числом

```
print(type(Q)
```

output: `<class 'complex'>`